# What is the best way to have my Java executable look for a dynamic file path (and save it) when reading files?

Tags: java, filepath

Basically what I'm trying to do is have my program read/load a `.txt` file in and process the data. Right now I have the file path hardcoded

> (ex: "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/testFolder/testFile.txt")

but if I export the `Jar` file and run it on a different pc, that file path will obviously not exist. Ideally, **I'd like the program to check if a file path was already entered (and stored)**, and if so use it, otherwise then it will prompt to enter a file path. I'm just getting hung up on how to hold this file path after the program ends.

Comment: One way to do it is using the [Java Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html).

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the importance of your program knowing details about files that exist on a different machine it’s run on before?

Comment: @Bohemian For example, the .txt file on computer A (fileA.txt) would contain a list of 20 items, but the .txt file on computer B (fileB.txt) will contain a list of 30 possibly different items. If I run the executable on computer A for the first time it won't have a directory so I'd add a pop-up to enter a file path which I'll need it to save somehow so that when I run it again on pc A it won't prompt for a directory since it was able to find the one stored. I could then run the same executable on pc B and it should run the same as on A (it doesn't have to remember the path from pc A)

Comment: @k314159 I’d say your suggestion is the ideal way. Consider posting it as an answer (before someone else does).

Comment: Indeed. @k314159 I do believe that's what I need. I've been messing around with some tutorials and examples I found since you posted, and I think it will work for my program. Thanks!